# Mapview geopoint is holding screen

Tags: android, android-mapview, projection

I'm having troubles on a simple task.

I'm trying to draw a square at the top left of the map shown below. (top left of the map projection)

[image]

But when I convert pixel 0,0 to latitude and longitude with TileSystem (`TileSystem.PixelXYToLatLong`) the point looks like it is drawn on the screen and not on the map... Why?

The code:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    // Translate point to x y coordinates on the screen

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Point point1_draw = new Point();
    Point point2_draw = new Point();
    Point point3_draw = new Point();
    Point point4_draw = new Point();

    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPointFromScreenCoords(0,0,mapView),
            point1_draw);
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPointFromScreenCoords(0,100,mapView),
            point2_draw);
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPointFromScreenCoords(100,0,mapView),
            point3_draw);
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPointFromScreenCoords(100,100,mapView),
            point4_draw);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    path.moveTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point2_draw.x, point2_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point3_draw.x, point3_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point4_draw.x, point4_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
    path.close();

     //canvas.drawCircle(120, 20, 15, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);


}`
```

I'm extending ItemizedOverlay. And this path is drawn on the screen and not on the map. So when i scrol away this path moves with the map... And I dont want that.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the screen and not on the map"?

Comment: I would like to draw a polygon that would blank a tile of a mapview.

What I am trying to say is, that the GeoPoints location is not on the mapview but on the screen. Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you overriding `draw` instead of `addItem`?

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soxX_3QYUVc) on how to draw on a map

Comment: Hi, tnx for the answer. But I think this is not what i'm looking for.

A google mapview is made out of tiles. Tile number varies on zoom value. I'm trying to paint a specific tile in black, so when the user enters a specific tile I would clear the black tile. I didn't find any usefull info. on the web how to do this.

I thought I could do this with a polygion that is bound by geopoints that are edges from a tile. 

But I dont know how to paint a tile at position [0,0]...

Comment: Here is a great picture:
http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC5902.jpg

How can I paint tile(0,0) to black?

Comment: You might want to create a `TableLayout` to achieve this.